# Mysql IF IN GROUP_CONCAT breaks

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Im doing a fairly big SQL so I apologizes that cant provide a bigger example of my tables.

```
SELECT 
customer_id,
agreement_id,
if( 'network' IN ( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT services.service_code
                                 SEPARATOR ',' )  ),
                  'Yes','No') as networkservice
FROM customers
INNER JOIN agreement USING(customer_id)
INNER JOIN services USING(agreement_id)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

A customer can have a agreement and a agreement can have a lot of services. What I'm trying to find out is if 'network' is one of the services in that agreement.

Since GROUP_CONCAT returns a comma separated list it feels perfect for my case. But I cant get it to work and I'm running out of ideas.

If there's only one service and that service is 'network' it returns yes, but if there's more then one it returns No.

If I use (INT)service_id instead it makes no difference, unless the INT Im looking for is first in the list. But thats only for INT, if 'network' is first in the list it returns No.

**I've tried:**

```
if( 'network' IN ( CAST(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT services.service_code
                                      SEPARATOR ' ' ) AS CHAR)  ),
                   'Yes','No')
```

And

```
if( 'network' IN ( concat('\'',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT services.service_code
                                SEPARATOR '\', \'' ),
                   '\'') ), 'Yes','No')
```

I can provide more examples if my explanation sound confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a **big fan** of `group_concat`, but you don't require `group_concat` in this case

```
sum( if(services.service_code='network', 1, 0) ) as networkservice
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought about using SUM. I used it like this `IF(sum( if(service.service_code='network', 1, 0) ) > 0 ,'Yes','No) as networkservice` and it works great.

Answer (score 9):

The `GROUP_CONCAT` function returns a string, so you can use `FIND_IN_SET`. It takes a comma separated string as a second argument.

```sql
IF(  FIND_IN_SET ('network', GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT services.service_code SEPARATOR ',' )  ), 'Yes','No') as networkservice
```

Comment: i highly appreciate this in Having clause (in my case). ;)

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work like this, the query after group_concat looks like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT('1,2,3,4')
```

and for this to work, it would have to look like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

Instead, try ommitting the group_concat: (note the unquoted `network`)

```
if(network IN (DISTINCT services.service_code) ), 'Yes','No')
```

If this doesn't work, try it with a sub-select:

```
if(network IN (SELECT service_code FROM services WHERE ...)
```

although it will be much slower.

Comment: `if( 'network' IN ( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT services.service_code SEPARATOR '\',\' ' )  ), 'Ja','Nej')` should return a list that looks like `GROUP_CONCAT('1', '2', '3', '4')`, feels that way anyway. But it doesn't work. Omitting the group_concat only works if 'network' is the service_code present on the row that Im grouping to, and I cant do Order By on service_code. Unquote networks breaks the sql. And I dont have the possibility to use a SubQuery. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Will using the below code help?

```
IF((GROUP_CONCAT(Direct SEPARATOR ',' ) REGEXP 'Y' ), 'Yes','No') AS Direct
```